# GWT id element is changing every time in selenium

Tags: java, gwt, selenium

```
selenium.click("gwt-uid-204"); // this is recorded from Selenium IDE
```

I am clicking the check box in my (gwt) java application. The gwt-uid is changing ever time, so if the id changed then my element is not found in my apps. The regular expression is not working for me and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help

```
selenium.click("gwt-uid-[0-9]);
```

I am using selenium 1.0.3, Java

Answer (score 15):

Many GWT elements comes with ensureDebugId (method on UIObject) to allow you to explicitly set Ids to elements for testing and debugging purpose. You also need to inherit the module

```
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
```

to make it work. The advantage of this is, you can remove the trace from the production deployment by removing the inherited module in during prod mode compile. Hence there wont be code changes to remove unnecessary Ids.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in 3/4 ways 
Can check this link : 
[3 ways of dealing with GWT dynamic element Ids](http://element34.ca/blog/google-web-toolkit-and-id)
which talks about 3 different ways of assigning a static id to your GWT elements.

Also, 
You can write a custom javascript method which will fetch all the ids dynamically. Then you can process those ids for selenium actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions. The first is to tell Se that you are using a regex by saying regex:gwt-uid-[0-9]. As you have it there it is looking the and element whose name or id is that literal string.

The other solution is to turn on static id's for things which I discuss in http://element34.ca/blog/google-web-toolkit-and-id.

-adam

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have dynamic IDs, as you have presented, first realize that Selenium's [click](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html#click) method takes a [locator](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html#locators) argument. A simple approach is to specify a locator that finds an ID starting with your constant "gwt-uid-" prefix. You can use any of these locators as the argument to your `click` method, depending on your preference of technologies:

```
  == XPath ==
   //input[starts-with(@id, 'gwt-uid-')]

  == CSS ==
   css=input[id^='gwt-uid-']

  == DOM ==
   dom=for each (e in document.getElementsByTagName('input')) if (e.id && (e.id.substr(0, 'gwt-uid-'.length) === 'gwt-uid-')) e
```

*Footnote 1*: I have not used GWT, so my examples above assume that it still puts a check box in an `<input>` element; adjust as needed.

*Footnote 2*: Selenium does offer regular expression support, as Adam intimated, but there are two issues with it in this case: (1) the prefix is "regexp:" rather than "regex:". (2) Selenium's `click` method does *not* support the regexp prefix at all! (My empirical evidence suggests that locators do not use regular expressions in Selenium, only text matching arguments do.)

Comment: If  all the dynamic ids are starting with 'gwt-uid-' how will you solve ? mostly the ids are gwt-uid-withsomenumber which is different across sessions.

Comment: All 3 of my examples address exactly that, so I am not sure what else you are asking. (Though technically I am not requiring a number to follow the prefix, but it is unlikely to get false positive matches from that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Firebug add ons to remove the GWT UID.

- Right click where the GWT UID is and select "inspect element with
  firebug" -
- Click on the code where the GWT UID is and when the firebug windows
  appears select "deleted attributes id"
- After removing the id, right click one more time and copy the "Xpath"
- Add an extra (/) and paste the xpath on the target.

[This](http://getfirebug.com/) may also help.