# GWT - using CssResource in Selenium tests

Tags: java, css, selenium, gwt, cssresource

Is it possible to use the generated `CssResource` in Selenium tests?

We run selenium tests at environment with obfuscated css classes, so i need `CssResource` to return obfuscated class names in tests.

Comment: when i'm using CssResource in Selenium tests i got error message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge.
And do i really need to include css file into selenium project?

Comment: And when i fixed this error with abstract GWTBridge class, i got another error 'GWT.create() is only usable in client code!'.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445034/gwt-id-element-is-changing-every-time-in-selenium

Comment: ensureDebugId is nice, but CssResource provide strongly typed css class names and i can easily get all usages it in tests and refactor.